# R studio shortcut to switch tabs:ctrl+alt+left/right not working

Tags: r, keyboard-shortcuts, rstudio

I am facing problems when using keyboard shortcuts to switch in between tabs in Rstudio: even though I have disabled the Hot Keys for the graphical card, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>left</kbd>/<kbd>right</kbd> to switch between tabs does not work. But, switching to first/last tab using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>left</kbd>/<kbd>right</kbd> is working. I am using the latest version of R, Rstudio, and Windows 7.

Has anyone an idea how to overcome this issue? (it seems I am not alone facing this problem : https://support.rstudio.com/hc/communities/public/questions/201564413-Keyboard-shortcut-not-working-on-Windows-7). Thank you for your answer.

Comment: I have the same setup and same issue. My keyboard shortcuts worked pretty recently but now don't. Would also appreciate a response if anyone has one.

Comment: Good news! After the latest update of R Studio (version  0.99.446), it seems that the shortcuts have changed : to switch to previous / next tab, one can now use [Ctrl] + [F11] and [Ctrl] + [F12]. Switching to first/last tab using [Ctrl] + [Alt] + [Shift] + [left] / [right] is still working.  I hope this can help you.

Answer (score 2):

If you have Intel:

1. go to Intel control Panel -> go to configurations
2. then change all combinations of buttons which rotate your screen to any other combnation (e.x.  Ctrl+Alt+left to  Alt+Shift+Q etc)
3. disable this function

Example is here : http://joxi.ru/Drl7Dp7TBwbwAP